# Android: Block Adsense ads in WebView

Tags: android, webview

I have a site which features advertisements from "Adsance". I also have an app for Android contains a "webview". I want to hide advertisements "Adsance", if the user opens my website through my application. What I need to do to hide ads in my "webview"?

Answer (score 2):

Pass mobile_app=1 in URL When website open through webview, Then catch mobile_app=1 through GET method in website. Write code in website:

```
if($_GET['mobile_app'] != 1)
{
 // Google ads 
}
```